# Azure Blob Storage successful requests show as failed requests in Application Insights

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-application-insights

The following container exists and hence returns failed request code 409

```
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("my-container");
container.CreateIfNotExists();
```

I do a check to make sure the Blob reference doesn't exist before creating. This returns a 404 response code with a bool.

```
if(container.GetBlockBlobReference("this-file-could-exist").Exists()) {
```

In the first example I expect the container to exist, in the second expect the file not to exist. But in both cases I do a check to make sure.

The code all works fine. The issue is that Application Insights alerts me to a heap of failed requests. Although these are not really failed requests there actually successful request because thats what I expect.

Whats the best way to resolve this? Can I make azure return 200 success or do I need to ignore these in Application Insights somehow.

Comment: Hi @John, any updates? do you solve the problem?

Comment: @FredHan, I was a bit stuck between both answers... I'm not keen to downgrade as I like to keep updated. The other answer was also good as it would change the 404, 409 etc to success, although if I was to try open a file and I got a 404 etc this would be a genuine failed request that would get marked as success.... I expected a Exists() etc to return a success code although it makes sense for it to also return a 404 if it doesn't. It just makes Insights list a heap of failures.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the latest version of the Storage Client Library, when you execute `CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists()` method, it actually execute create operation, so sometimes server response will be 409.

**Source code of version 8.2.0**

[image]
If possible, you can try to downgrade your Storage Client Library version to v7.2.1.

**Source code of version 7.2.1**

[image]

I execute the following code in my **About** action, I can find the **Result code** in application insight is **200**.

```
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

container.CreateIfNotExists();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to add a telemetry processor to your app that throws away things you don't ever want to see.

in this sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling

```
// Example: replace with your own criteria.
private bool OKtoSend (ITelemetry item)
{
    var dependency = item as DependencyTelemetry;
    if (dependency == null) return true;

    return dependency.Success != true;
}
```

they have a telemetry processor that just flat out ignores any dependency calls that succeeded, only sending telemetry for *failed* dependencies.

you could write similar logic and just filter out dependencies that were 409's, or you could modify dependencies that were 409's and mark them as success instead of failures.