# Alternative for BlobContainerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync method to avoid 409 http error

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, azure-blob-storage, datadog

**Prerequisites**

- WindowsAzure.Storage V 9.3.3
- Azure.Storage.Blobs V 12.6.0
- Datadog APM monitoring

**Context:**

1. This is a known problem, that a blob client `CreateIfNotExists(Async)` returns 409 during execution, in case if a container already has been created before
2. Due to existed implementation, the `CreateIfNotExists` check is executing per a request, that mean a lot of times
3. As a result, there are a lot of 409 errors in a log & monitor systems
4. Also, it's kind of challenge to move logic to the app root, and, thus, to avoid per request `CreateIfNotExists` check

**The possible fix, under consideration:**

To mitigate the issue, I gonna to replace it with something like:

```
if (!await blobClient.ExistsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
{
   await containerClient.CreateAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

**Question:** And one moment that bothering me:

- Could be such replacement become a concern within high concurrent workflow ?

**P.s** I've looked into `CreateIfNotExistsAsync` implementation at '`Azure.Storage.Blobs`' nuget. From my point of view, nothing special about concurrency, but maybe I'm wrong. Pls. share you experience

[image]

Comment: HTTP error 409 usually means "There is a conflict".  There is something wrong with your query that is producing this error.  Most likely the object already exists and you are trying to add it a 2nd time.  Best thing is to check if it exists before adding.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893519/azure-table-storage-exception-409-conflict-unexpected

Comment: `the CreateIfNotExists check is executing per a request, that mean a lot of times` *that* is the real problem. Cache the first response and *don't* try to check again.  You can avoid both the exception and the double HTTP calls by using HttpClient to execute a direct call *but* that still means you're making 1 HTTP a lot of times even when the response isn't expected to change

Comment: As for 409 itself, your code will have to handle it. The existence check won't help. That's simply the nature of all cloud applications. [The source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/src/BlobContainerClient.cs) shows that the method *already* handles an existing container situation and returns `null`. 409 means two attempts to call `Create` were made concurrently.

Comment: The best way to reduce 409s is to *reduce* the chance of identical concurrent calls. If that's not possible, you could ignore or retry in case of conflicts. After all, a 409 means some other request is creating the container so *probably* that container will be there when you try to use it. If not, it means there was a big delay on *Azure's* side, or/and that creation failed. To guard against delays you can call `ExistsAsync` if ``CreateIfNotExists` fails with a 409, until the container appears. Calling `CreateIfNotExists` again also handles failed creations. In every case you're making 1 call

Comment: If you use Polly you could create a retry policy for this type of problem, eg retrying after a delay if 409 occurs

Comment: Did suggested code work? I am also getting a 409 error every time I check a table if it existis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will have to handle this problem. Checking for existence won't help.

The problem is concurrency on *the server side*, not concurrency in the client. [The source shows](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/src/BlobContainerClient.cs#L1070) that`CretaeIfNotExists` already handles the case of an existing container by simply ignoring the exception. One could ask *why* an exception is thrown instead of checking the status code, but the code *doesn't* throw a 409 if a container exists:

```
try
{
    response = await CreateInternal(
        publicAccessType,
        metadata,
        encryptionScopeOptions,
        async,
        cancellationToken,
        operationName)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (RequestFailedException storageRequestFailedException)
when (storageRequestFailedException.ErrorCode == BlobErrorCode.ContainerAlreadyExists)
{
    response = default;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ClientConfiguration.Pipeline.LogException(ex);
    scope.Failed(ex);
    throw;
}
finally
{
    ClientConfiguration.Pipeline.LogMethodExit(nameof(BlobContainerClient));
    scope.Dispose();
}
return response;
```

For a conflict to occur, two `CreateInternal` calls would have to try to create the same non-existent container. That's why checking for existence won't help here. Even if an existence check was used, both clients would still try to execute `Create` at the same time and both would get a `409`.

The application will have to handle this case. The best option would be *reducing* the chance of conflicts by *not* making this call on every request. This could be done by using eg a `Lazy<>` or asynchronous Lazy to make this call. Or using queued workers, reducing the number of calls that can happen at the same time.

The application would still have to handle the occasional 409. One way would be to simply retry `CreateIfNotExists` after a delay, until the call succeeds. That's better than calling `Exists` because the container's creation could fail.

Comment: This is incorrect. Our container exists and we get over 100K errors logged as dependency errors in Application Insights.

Comment: @LarryFlewwelling I link to the actual source code. Either the source code lies, or the errors are due to a different call. Git Blame shows the check was added in 2020, so it's not a recent change

Answer (score 2):

```
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

            if (!containerClient.Exists())
            {
                containerClient = await blobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainerAsync(containerName, PublicAccessType.BlobContainer);
            }
```

Comment: This will have no effect, [the method already handles an existing container](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/src/BlobContainerClient.cs). Conflicts will occur if *multiple* `Create` requests happen concurrently

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to chime in here because I suspect the cause for concern here is not what the MS is or is not doing, its what Datadog is doing as I just dealth with this issue this morning. The OP is using Datadog as their APM, another user mentioned AppInsights. At the end of the day the APM wouldn't matter but the use of one will cause these false-positive errors. The APM is observing the 409 in the response from the blob storage service itself. Regardless of whether or not a library catches and eats it or not, the blob service is still returning a 409 and its response code is observed by the APM. The 409's are being caught and handled by the MS lib and the 409 response to the attempt to create a container that already exists, as the call needs to be idempotent and cannot rely on checks due to concurrency concerns, is completely expected.

The solution to this problem lies in the configuration of the APM, not in the application code. In our case, given that we have a blob persistence logic encapsulated in our own class that handles the container/blob interaction along with logging and other elements, was to configure the APM to ignore 409's from a specific method within the class and moved the call to create the BlobContainerClient and CreateIfNotExistAsync to the new method now being conditionally ignored by the APM. This does not impact 409's for other operations, including those dealing with the contents of the blobs and avoids the substantial number of 409's which are returned while implementing the best practices of using CreateIfNotExist.

**Note**: I think some responders might have overlooked the fact that it is very common to have a container, not blob, but a container, used to store related content in blobs. Just like you would use a folder to store related files. In our case, we had a container named "content" which has hundreds of thousands of files in it, which, if we wanted to implement custom logic or DevOps processes to pre-create them, we could and then skip the code to CreateIfNotExist but that is brittle. The 409's in this use case are both expected and necessary outside of creating highly coupled code, try/catch/retry for first attempts or some external out of band process such as a DevOps pipeline. Microsoft was aware of this and provides a client to solve this common dilemma and for not the APM, the OP would not have known it was occurring.

Comment: You observations are correct, but hiding the 409s is not a good general resolution. If your business process accepts the over-heads of being highly decoupled, then sure you can ignore this, but if your logs are showing a 409 for every write attempt, and you make them with high frequency then we can improve the workflow and bandwidth by skipping some or all of these exists checks. It is good that APM highlights this type of inefficient code so that we can have these sorts of conversations.